# Backbone - use different views or templates for same collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

The base model of my application has a `status` attribute.
Let's assume, for simplicity, that status might be either **pending** or **deleted**.

I have an upper menu with these two status values, when you click one of them you see all objects with this status (I use router to trigger a filter).

My problem is that I need to draw a different template for each status.

- **deleted** object has **delete forever** and **recover** buttons
- **pending** object has **delete**, **edit** and some other buttons (also some textarea...)

I wonder what would be the best solution for this problem.
I thought of creating a different view for each status, but then I don't know how to deal with it in the collection level.
I also thought of creating different templates and deal with it in the model-view level, but again - I have no idea whether it is possible and if yes - how.

Finally, I can solve it with same template and view, hiding what is not necessary inside the view, but then the code becomes quite ugly in my point of view.

Ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a different view for each status, you do it this way :

```
Router {

    clickDeletedMenu : {

        var collection = new MyCollection();
        var deletedView = new DeletedView({ model : collection });

        collection.fetch({ status : 'deleted' }); // filter deleted objects
    },

    clickPendingMenu : {

        var collection = new MyCollection();
        var pendingView = new PendingView({ model : collection });

        collection.fetch({ status : 'pending' }); // filter deleted objects
    },

}
```

If you want to create differents templates, you do it this way :

```
View {

    render : {

        if (this.model.status == 'deleted') {
            // render deleted template
        } else {
            // render pending template
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in my point of view, you can use the same template and view, and hiding what is not necessary inside the template not the view.

**nb** : the code is used just to illustrate the idea, it's not going to execute :)

Comment: Thanks, great! Actually I got to anther solution. I created a viewBase which I extend to viewDeleted and viewPending (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9424768/1039488), and then in then collection I do `var viewClassName = item.get('status') + "View"` and use `eval` to create the corresponding view. I do it since I find it easier to have everything in the same collection (it si my first backbone app..)